# How to set the home screen sideways

Tags: lock-screens, home-screen, android-versions

Usually apps, settings etc. set automatically sideways when you turn your phone horizontal and if your "Screen rotation" is enabeld.
[image]

But why does the home screen/ lockscreen does not set to horizonal view automatically as in the picture above? Always when I try it, it does not work like these:
[image]

**Now, I would like to know how to set the home screen/ lock sideways generally! That means by all andrid phones of all producers with this problem.**

Comment: 1. the app must support auto-rotation (not all homescreens do). 2. for some homescreens, you must explicitely enable it in their settings. 3. According to the 3rd screenshot, your Android version is quite outdated :)

Comment: There is no "generic answer" to this, Bully. Check the settings of your homescreen app if you find something – if not, it might simply not support it. In the latter case, your only option is using an [alternative launcher](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_launcher).

Comment: As for the lockscreen,, setting it to autorotation will require your device to be rooted along with some third party root apps. Please provide additional details such as make/model and android version.

Answer (score 2):

Custom launchers like `Nova Launcher` can rotate sideways. Unfortunately a `stock launcher` can't do that.